# iTextSharp Tables : Rows not displaying

Tags: c#, .net, itext, pdfptable

I have a problem using tables with iTexSharp version 5.5.7.0 .

I want to build a catalog of products which are groupped by categories and sub categories.

I need to display the category name, the sub caregory name and the products in it.
When the sub category changes, i need to repeat the category name :

```
Category 1 
  Sub category 1
    Product 1 table 
    Product 2 table...
Category 1
  Sub category 2
    Product 1 table ...
Category 2 
  Sub category 1
    Product 1 table 
    Product 2 table...
Category 2 
  Sub category 2
    Product 1 table 
    Product 2 table
    Product 3 table...
```

The thing is i don't want the category and sub category names to be displayed at the bottom of a page and having the first product of this sub category to be displayed on the following page.

So i created a tableContainer in which i add tableCategory, tableSubCategory and the first tableProduct.

I add this tabContainer to the document, then i add a table with the remaining products.
I tried to use KeepTogether, SplitRows and SplitLate but with no sucess.
Sometimes it seems to work but there are rows which are not diplayed on the page like :

```
End of Page :
  Category  
    Sub category 
New Page :  
    Product 2 table...
    Product 3 table...
```

The product 1 table is missing

My document is A4 size with margins :

```
 pdfDocument =  pdfDocument = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 40, 40);
 pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream(path, fileMode));
```

The way i display data in the document :

```
PdfPTable tableContainer = CreateTable(new float[] { 100f }, false, 0f, 0f,    pdfDocument.PageSize.Width);
tableContainer.SplitRows = false;
tableContainer.KeepTogether = true;

foreach (string category in categoriesList)
{
     //Cell category
    PdfPCell cellCategory = CreateCell(category, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Oswald", Rectangle.NO_BORDER, 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE, lightBlueColor, 1, 30);


foreach (string subCategory in subCategoriesList)
{   
     //Cell sub category
    PdfPCell cellSubCategory = CreateCell(category, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Oswald", Rectangle.NO_BORDER, 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE, lightBlueColor, 1, 30);

    tableContainer.AddCell(cellCategory);
    tableContainer.AddCell(cellSubCategory);

    //table with list of products
    PdfPTable productsTable = CreateTable(new float[] { 100f }, false, 0f, 10f, pdfDocument.PageSize.Width - (pdfDocument.LeftMargin + pdfDocument.RightMargin) - 40);

    foreach (Product p in productsFilteredList)
    {
        //Create product Table
        PdfPTable productTable = CreateProductTable(pdfDocument, p);

        //If first product : category , sub category and first product must be displayed together on the same page
        if(firstProduct)
            tableContainer .AddCell(productTable);              
        else
            productsTable.AddCell(productTable); 
    }

    pdfDocument.Add(tableContainer);
    pdfDocument.Add(productsTable);
}
}


private  PdfPTable CreateProductTable(Document pdfDocument, product p)
{
PdfPTable productTable = CreateTable(new float[] { 25f, 20f, 35f, 10f, 10f }, false, 0f, 0f, pdfDocument.PageSize.Width - (pdfDocument.LeftMargin + pdfDocument.RightMargin) - 40);

PdfPCell cellImage = CreateCellImage(tempFolderPhotosPath + p.Code + ".jpeg", 50f, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, Rectangle.UNDEFINED, 60f);
cellImage.PaddingLeft = 30f;
productTable.AddCell(cellImage);

productTable.AddCell(CreateCell(p.Code, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "Oswald", Rectangle.NO_BORDER, 7, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK, backGroundColor, 1, productTable.DefaultCell.Height));
productTable.AddCell(CreateCell(p.Description, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Oswald", Rectangle.NO_BORDER, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK, backGroundColor, 1, productTable.DefaultCell.Height));
productTable.AddCell(CreateCell(p.Reference, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "Oswald", Rectangle.NO_BORDER, 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK, backGroundColor, 1, productTable.DefaultCell.Height));
productTable.AddCell(CreateCell(p.Price , Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "Oswald", Rectangle.NO_BORDER, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK, backGroundColor, 1, productTable.DefaultCell.Height));
return productTable;
}

private  PdfPCell CreateCell(string content, int verticalAlignement, int horizontalAlignement, string fontName, int border, int fontSize, int fontStyle, BaseColor fontColor, BaseColor backgroundColor, int rowSpan, float minHeight)
{
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(content, FontFactory.GetFont(fontName, fontSize, fontStyle, fontColor))));
cell.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignement;
cell.VerticalAlignment = verticalAlignement;
cell.Border = border;
cell.Rowspan = rowSpan;
cell.MinimumHeight = minHeight;
cell.Border = border;

return cell;
}

private  PdfPCell CreateCellImage(string pathImage, float widthPercentage, int verticalAlignement, int horizontalAlignement, int rowSpan, int border, float minHeight)
{
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.HorizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignement;
cell.VerticalAlignment = verticalAlignement;
cell.Border = border;
cell.Rowspan = rowSpan;
cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

Image image = Image.GetInstance(pathImage);
image.ScaleToFit(widthPercentage, minHeight);

cell.MinimumHeight = minHeight + 10;
cell.AddElement(image);

return cell;
}
```

I need a way to link tables and force them to be displayed on the same page. And if it does not fit in the sapce remaining of the current page then automatically create a new page.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this ? 
Thanks.